# ng-repeat is not working with the key value pair when key has special character($)

Tags: angularjs

ng-repeat is not working with the key value pair when key has special character($)

for an example

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in values">{{key}}</div>
```

where values is equal to

```
$scope.values = {
      $firstName:"Kusum";
      lastName:"Kumari"
}
```

its prints the `lastNAme` but it is failing for `$firstName`.

Comment: Can you post your example javascript and html snippet?

Comment: why did you add '$' to firstname variable ?
use the same logic every where `$scope.values = {
      firstName:"Kusum",
      lastName:"Kumari"
}` NOTE : use `,` to separe element not `;`

Comment: My json is coming in this format only, So i need to handled it this way.http://plnkr.co/edit/ToP7FgXtsTAwIUOt7V6O?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Access it like

```
{{Obj["$firstName"]}}
```

**Notice**: the `double` `quotes`

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: The square bracket notation usualy can contain special characters where as the dot notation cannot.

Comment: as object to iterate over is dynamic, I am not sure, which key will have this $symbol, So i need a fix, which should works for anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected, as [stated in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> ngRepeat will silently ignore object keys starting with $, because
>   it's a prefix used by Angular for public ($) and private ($$)
>   properties.

You could change the attributes that begin with a `$` in your controller.

```
for (var property in $scope.values) {
    if ($scope.values.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if(property[0] === '$'){
          $scope.values["_"+property] = $scope.values[property]
        }
    }
}
```

And you can clean the object afterwards

```
 $scope.clean = function(){
    for (var property in $scope.values) {
      if ($scope.values.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          if(property[0] === '_'){
            console.log($scope.values)
            delete $scope.values[property]
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X2wXGz?p=preview)

Comment: It is known to me, but still looking for some solution, As i can't avoid it.

Comment: @KusumKushwaha check it out

Comment: thanks for this the solution, I found one more solution for it, Please check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ToP7FgXtsTAwIUOt7V6O?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You were building the variable in wrong way. Here is a working example.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [];
  $scope.values[0]= {};
    $scope.values[0] = {
      $firstName:"Kusum",
      lastName:"Kumari"
}
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    

      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in values">{{value.$firstName}}-{{value.lastName}}</div>

    

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since the response is dynamic, I could not avoid $ from key. I need a solution to fix this issue asap.

Comment: @KusumKushwaha i m not saying you should avoid $ from key. you just build the $scope.value variable wrong. check the difference between ur and my variable

Answer (score 0):

You can make use `Object.keys` and a method which returns an `Array`, which you can iterate through. i.e.

```
  $scope.keys = function(value) {
    return value ? Object.keys($scope.values):[];
  }
```

You can use this `keys` variable in the template

```
<div ng-repeat="key in keys(values)">
    {{key}} : {{values[key]}}
</div>
```